# How can I select a server in system-config-printer?

Tags: printing, gnome, cups, lubuntu

The server dialog in the Linux administration tool `system-config-printer` looks like this:

[image]

However, the CUPS server may not be on localhost but on a remote machine.  How can one tell `system-config-printer` this?  The input field is fixed and does not allow any changes.  Is there a configuration file that could help?

What you see is `system-config-printer` v1.5.7 on Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Sorry for residual German translations in the image: "Hinzufügen" means "to add", "Nicht verbunden" means "not connected", and "Drucker" means "printer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the environmental variable `CUPS_SERVER` set?

```
echo $CUPS_SERVER
```

If it is not set, or shows the wrong setting, try running `system-config-printer` with the correct variable

```
CUPS_SERVER=myprintserver system-config-printer
```

You might want to have it as a permanent global setting. If so, add it to `/etc/environment`.